# Cheking if div is visible

Tags: jquery, css, dom, visibility

I'm using Popcorn.js and it creates the following HTML code:

```
<div id="row-1">
    <div style="display: none;">Hello</div>
</div>
```

But now I'm trying to add/remove `.myClass` to `.test` using jQuery when the div inside of `#row1` is `display: inline`.

I've tried `.height()`, `.lenght()` and `.width()` (but this one doesn't work, because the width of the div is always `1246px`)

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

---

** **EDIT** **

The whole HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://popcornjs.org/code/dist/popcorn-complete.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

        <style>
        .myClass{
          background: yellow !important;
        }
        </style>

    <script>
      // ensure the web page (DOM) has loaded
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

           // Create a popcorn instance by calling the Youtube player plugin
         var example = Popcorn.youtube(
           '#video',
           'https://www.youtube.com/embed/w9l4v1s9148?controls=1' );

         example.footnote({
           start: 1.2,
           end: 1.7,
           text: "Hello",
           target: "row-1"
         });

         example.footnote({
           start: 1.7,
           end: 3.2,
           text: "boys and girls",
           target: "a2"
         });

         example.footnote({
           start: 3.2,
           end: 4.8,
           text: "my name is FatLip,",
           target: "a3"
         });

         example.footnote({
           start: 4.8,
           end: 7,
           text: "and this is my friend, Simon the Salmon.",
           target: "a4"
         });


      }, false);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="video" style="width: 360px; height: 300px;" ></div>

  <div id="row-1"></div>
  <div id="a2"></div>
  <div id="a3"></div>
  <div id="a4"></div>

  <div class="test" style="width: 10px; height: 10px; background: black;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try with `$(el).is(":visible")`

Answer (score 13):

jQuery has selector [visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) so You can check `.is(':visible')`

Answer (score 4):

To see if the child div is visible, you can do the following -

> $('#row-1').children().is(':visible')
>
> !$('#row-1').children().is(':hidden')
>
> $('#row-1').children().css('display') == 'none'

But to answer your question, you can do something like this -

If you want to look for `display: inline`, you can do the following -

> $('#row-1').children().filter('div[style*=display: inline]').addClass('**myClass**')

If you want to see if it's visible and then add / remove class, you can do the following -

> $('#row-1').children().filter(':hidden').addClass('**myClass**') // or removeClass

Comment: `none` is not a declared variable

Comment: Sorry.. Didn't notice that

Answer (score 3):

Since the first div has an id we can use it to grab its first child and check to see if that child's display value is equal to inline.

```
// pure javascript

if (document.getElementById('row-1').firstChild.style.display === 'inline') {
    // add/remove class
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is the right answer, but you might want to expand it a bit to explain why this solves the problem